# Check if facebook user voted already

Tags: php, facebook, vote

I have built a Facebook app. its a contest app and i allow them to recommend different non-profits to be voted on. but they have to like my fan-page first not allow my app.

my question is how do i check if a user voted already. i cant set a cookie so i have to check somehow. what i want to do is to store some data whats unique to that user in my database so i can check when the page loads to see if they voted already. I am using php in the Facebook app.

I was thinking about something like this.

equire 'facebook/facebook.php';

```
            // Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
            $facebook = new Facebook(array(
              'appId' => 'APP_ID',
              'secret' => 'APP_SECRET',
            ));

            $user = $facebook->getUser();

            if ($user) {

             // Add to database
            }

            // rest of code here
```

Comment: Can you supply the rest of the code, that of which triggers the vote. You'll only want to add the user id to the database once they have submitted a vote, and then upon re-visit use their id to check the database for it's existence.

Comment: Well what i ma doing is pulling the nominated non-profits from my database and displaying them in with a php while loop with some basic html and css. here is the query

$query = "SELECT * FROM non_profits ORDER BY `non_profits `.`votes` DESC LIMIT 3"; 

now in the HTML form i add the non profit's ID in an hidden feild and i do a simple update

mysql_query("UPDATE non_profits SET votes=votes+1 WHERE vanity_code='$Up_vanity_code' ")or die(mysql_error());

Comment: Can't you just log something in your database logging the Facebook user ID of the voter and the poll they voted on, and use that database to not allow duplicate votes?

Comment: I can but i ma not sure how to get the users id. i am not asking them to authenticate my app just to like my fan page

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot get the user's id unless they have authenticated your application. It will always return 0 otherwise.